# React Native list view not displaying the data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am developing a simple React native iOS application just to learn React Native and this is my first react native app. Now, I am practising of using ListView. But seems like the items are loaded into list view but data are not displayed.

This is my reducer

```
import * as AlbumListActions from '../actions/AlbumListActions';

const defaultState = {
    albums: [ ],
    loading: false,
    message: null
}

export default albumListReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AlbumListActions.ALBUMS_START_FETCHING_ALBUMS:
            return { ...state, loading: true, albums: [ ] }
            break;

        case AlbumListActions.ALBUMS_COMPLETE_FETCHING_ALBUMS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, albums: action.payload }
            break;

        case AlbumListActions.ALBUMS_CATCH_FETCHING_ALBUMS:
            return { ...state, loading: false, message: action.payload }
            break;

        default:
            return { ...state };
    }
}
```

This is my action

```
import Axios from 'axios';

export const ALBUMS_START_FETCHING_ALBUMS = "(albums) start fetching albums";
export const ALBUMS_COMPLETE_FETCHING_ALBUMS = "(albums) complete fetching albums";
export const ALBUMS_CATCH_FETCHING_ALBUMS = "(albums) catch fetching albums";

export const completeFetchingAlbums = (data) => {
    return {
        type: ALBUMS_COMPLETE_FETCHING_ALBUMS,
        payload: data
    }
}

export const catchFetchingAlbums = (data) => {
    return {
        type : ALBUMS_CATCH_FETCHING_ALBUMS,
        payload: data
    }
}

export const fetchAlbums = (data) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: ALBUMS_START_FETCHING_ALBUMS
        });

        return Axios.get("http://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums").then((response) => {
            dispatch(completeFetchingAlbums(response.data));
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch(catchFetchingAlbums("Unable to fetch data from the server"));
        })
    }
}
```

This is my component rendering list view.

```
class AlbumList extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchAlbums();
    }

    renderAlbumItem = (album) => {
        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>{album.title}</Text>
                </View>
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
            <FlatList
                data={this.props.albums}
                renderItem={this.renderAlbumItem}
                keyExtractor={(album) => album.title}
            />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state.albumList;
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        fetchAlbums : AlbumListActions.fetchAlbums
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AlbumList);
```

When I run my app, it is not displaying anything. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your `FlatList` re-rendering after the fetch is done ?

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: just `console.log(this.props.albums)` in the `render` method, before the `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `renderItem` is wrong. It accepts an object that one of its properties is `item` which holds the album you're trying to render.

So to make it work, change `renderItem` as follows:

```
renderAlbumItem({item}) => {
    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </View>
        )
}
```

You can also rename `item` to `album` - `renderAlbumItem({item: album})`. This syntax is called object destructuring, you can google for an explanation. In that case use `{album.title}` to access the title.

Comment: It is saying undefined is not an object. If I do not use FlatList, I am getting all the data right.

Comment: This works. I needed to use album.title in the renderAlbumItem method. Cheers.